# sqlserver alwayson audit setting

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019, audit, enterprise-edition

I am running SQLSERVER ALWAYS ON 2019 ENT VERSION.

I'm trying to STOCK an audit at the database level in SQLSERVER.

In the master, it was confirmed that the log audit was left at DATABASE LEVEL.

However, I want to leave an audit log in SLAVE.

I wish you could tell me how.

I want to leave an audit log in SLAVE.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Try asking in DBA stackexchange.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question seems administrative.

Comment: Also note that the <sql> tag is for questions regarding the SQL _language_.